# Estimating Population Total of a Lognormal distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, lognormal-distribution

Say we’re trying to model spending behavior and it has a lognormal distribution, lognormal(6.4, 0.8) with N=1000 independent observations, a vector named A.

What’s the expected value of the total spend from this population and the associated uncertainty?

Is the expected value of the total spends point estimate simply $sum(A)$? Or is it $\text{exp}(6.4 + 0.5 \times 0.8^2) \times N$ (the expected value of the distribution times the number of observations)? Or is it something else entirely?

I’ve found a ton of resources about adding multiple lognormal distributions, but I can’t seem to find anything about the population total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the expected value for a single sample times the number of samples. sum(A) is the actual value of your samples (i.e. not an expectation). There won't be any uncertainty regarding sum(A) - the samples are the samples, so imagine them as actual customers making purchases. The estimate of what those samples look like comes from the distribution itself.

Comment: Great thank you! Makes sense to me, I just ran simulations that lined up with that as well